# Filter class properties and create a new class (.cs file)

Tags: c#, code-generation

I have around 500 class files (.cs) and all of them have have more or less the following structure

```
        public class InvoiceHeader
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public int Costs { get; set; }
            public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
            ......
            ......
        }
```

All properties are only built-in c# types (string, int(?), long(?), bool, DateTime,..). No lists or custom types.

Sometimes a class has over 300 properties and I want to filter e.g all ID properties and generate a new .cs file which has all properties exactly like the original one, excluding all properties ending with "ID" (as an example). Is there any way to achieve this? I have literally no idea how to start. I appreciate any help!

Comment: `findstr /V Id .\MyClass.cs >MyClassWithoutId.cs` could do... Not sure how it is related to C# so - some clarification of your restrictions on tools may make it more on-topic

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019